# Augment request-promise-native module with new functionality

Tags: typescript

How to augment `request-promise-native` with new method to have my own behaviour.

I tried as below but Typescript complains with error `getCached is not function`

```
const req = require('request');
import 'request-promise-native';

declare module 'request' {
interface RequestAPI<TRequest extends Request, TOptions extends CoreOptions, TUriUrlOptions> {
    getCached(): number;
}
}

req.getCached = function () {
//other specific logic
}
module.exports = req
```